# How can I call a C# server function from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I send a C# function call from SQL Server? I have a SQL Server 2008 database and a C# web server but the SQL Server database is hosted on a provider that does not allow emails from SQL Server so I need to send a C# function call to the web server when a record is inserted so I can send emails from the web server.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you need to send the information to a server other than the one that made the insert to the SQL server?

Comment: You *could* potentially write a C# SQL-CLR assembly.... but that seems like the totally wrong approach..... why don't you put an application on your web server which polls a table that contains the data needed to send out the e-mails? Anytime you need an e-mail, you just add a row to that table from your SQL Server code. Seems just soooooo much simpler....

Comment: What a circular mess that is. I would create a table in sql that holds information about emails that need to be sent. Then create a process on your webserver to pick up that information and send the emails. Finally remove those rows from your table.

Comment: hehe seems that @marc_s posted the same response I did a few seconds earlier. :)

Comment: seems that you both posted the same response I posted in an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

There really is no way to do this (esp. if you have a provider that does not allow emails they won't allow embedded C# I'm sure.

The best way is to write a program that runs on your server and queries the DB to look for changes... when it sees a change it sends an email.

or as marc_s and sean lange point out, you could have the SQL server control all the rules and write to a table of email content.  Then your client app would just read what to do from that table and send the emails.

Putting the logic in the client or on the server depends on which you want to control the process.

Comment: How would you suggest I get the web server to check for record updates on the SQL server. I don't want to slow down the website too much.

Comment: @user3746002 - don't pre-optimize, unless you are making really poor code you should not have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my data update to an online system instead of Access front end meaning that after update i use the webserver to send the emails. took a little time but works well

Answer (score -1):

You may create a [SQL Server User-Defined Function or Procedure using CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx).

Here's a link to an [example that uses this approach to send email](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1795/send-email-from-sql-server-express-using-a-clr-stored-procedure/).

Comment: clearly he can't do this, he can't even send an email on the server using the built in email functionality of sql server.  You think the hosting provider would allow him to load code into their sql server specifically to get around their stated policy?